# How do you bootstrap Zend Framework 2.5 unit tests?

Tags: zend-framework2

None of the example bootstrap files that worked for < ZF2.4 work with the latest version of ZF, 2.5. Has anyone seen a working example of unit testing a ZF2.5 app?

Comment: I've tested this morning, with my 2.4 old Architecture, it seems, it works with 2 changes on the autoloader part and my tests running with somes warnings, so for me it's possible. Did you solved your problem or you need help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 2 things in the Bootstrap
in line 66 where you must add a new elseif that looks like this.

```
    if (!$zf2Path) {
        if (defined('ZF2_PATH')) {
            $zf2Path = ZF2_PATH;
        } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library')) {
            $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library';
        } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library')) {
            $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library';
        } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework')) {
            $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework';
        }
    }
```

and in line 91 you must change this

```
include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
```

to this

```
 include $zf2Path . '/zend-loader/src/AutoloaderFactory.php';
```

also see here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#comment-2175935800